# How to Share GPS Location iOS

Tags: iphone, geolocation, share

I have seen some apps that offer functionality to share location via email or SMS. I have done a good amount of searching and haven't found much regarding this. Is it because all that is shared are the longitude, latitude information (thus being very simple)?

Comment: What you want to share latitude longitude ? location of user?

Comment: I want to share the user's curent location, yes. So latidude and longitude of their current position.

Answer (score 0):

You need to grab location information and use a transportation medium (email, TCP/IP, HTTP) to send it to a remote site. There is no **automatic** way of sharing that.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to fetch Current location of user with the help of core location and with the help of this latitude longitude you can share a google map link to other user via facebook, gmail or any social media.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CLLocationManager to subscribe for location updates. They are happening asynchronously and every second. You may control precision and some other parameters. Once you get it, you need to push a notification to another device thru your service or something like Urban Airship. I build my app like that https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/citrus-location/id777381230?ls=1&mt=8.

Here is more info from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html